# Many requsets(CRUD) to backend in one useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, crud

I have one simple question. In my ToDo list app, created using React, I have many requests to the server (at list 4 requests with a different methods - GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE), where should I write them ? If I did it in one `useEffect`, I guess I will need use conditions `if()` in it. Is it the right approach to build apps in React with CRUD operations ?

My app:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

function MainList() {
  const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState('');
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState([])
  const [toDo, setToDo] = useState([])
  const [taskAdd, setTaskAdd] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (taskAdd) {
      fetch('/server/someId', {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({...profile, list: toDo})
      }).then(res => setTaskAdd(false))
    } else {
      fetch('/server/someId')
        .then(res => {
          const currentAccount = res.find(el => el.status);         
          // Here we take our current account, where store all it
          // tasks. Response from the server will be array of object's(accounts), 
          // and when user login(from previous
          // login page), we change in his account (object) key - 'status' from false to true, 
          // for understanding who
          // exactly was login and take his data to work with.
          setProfile(currentAccount);
          setToDo(currentAccount.list);
        })
    }

  }, [taskAdd])


  const suby = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const goal = {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1 + '',
      task: newTask
    }
    setToDo([...toDo, goal])
    setTaskAdd(true)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>ToDo List</h1>
      <form onSubmit={suby}>
        <label>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(event) => setNewTask(event.target.value)}
            value={newTask}
          />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Add task</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {toDo.map(el => <li key={el.id}>{el.task}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MainList;
```

Comment: If there's no particular problem with this code, then Yes is the answer.

Comment: Looking at your code you aren't doing anything with the *data* received, *I hope you know what you are doing*, otherwise check MDN [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: No, you shouldn't use `useEffect` for this.

`useEffect` is a React Hook that lets you synchronize a component with an **external system**.

Read more [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect).

Comment: For CRUD operations I highly recommend using [react-query](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/). From a quick Google, I found a simple TODO list project that is using react-query. Check it out: https://github.com/ndraaditiya/React-Query-Axios

Comment: To clarify my Yes answer is for the "*Is it the right approach to build apps in React with CRUD operations ?*" (Hint: *your grammar made me think you are asking if you should do CRUD operations at ALL in React*). Code-wise `useEffect` is quite doable for this, and many YouTube tutorials will show you this. However for other than GET requests you would wanna `fetch` inside an Event Handler function. While the suggested *React Query* way above is the newer and better approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just have some concerns of using `useEffect`.

This all depends on when you want to call the API, most of time, people want to invoke the API after the mount, so `useEffect` can help to invoke them. But if you decide to invoke it upon a mouse click etc, then you most likely wire it with a `onClick` handler. So `useEffect` isn't the only place.

Whether you can put one or two api calls inside one `useEffect` or two, that's really up to you, because all `useEffect` calls are stacked and bundled to be invoked after the current DOM render, so if you have two `useEffect` (even inside two different components), they will be all invoked one after another one.

Answer (score -1):

you can make custom hooks for data fetching by passing API URL as function parameter.

```
    //hook

    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

    function useFetch(url) {
      const [data, setData] = useState(null);
      const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
      const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          try {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            const data = await response.json();
            setData(data);
          } catch (error) {
            setError(error);
          } finally {
            setIsLoading(false);
          }
        };
    
        fetchData();
      }, [url]);
    
      return { data, isLoading, error };

}

/// component



function MyComponent() {
      const url="any"
      const { data, isLoading, error } = useFetch(url);
    
      if (isLoading) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
      }
    
      if (error) {
        return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Data</h1>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
      );
    }
```